# How to measure the length of y?

Tags: r

Im new to R and face some problems determining the length of y till y=1 happens. 
Given sample:

```
         id<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,2) 
         y<-c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,1) 
         time<-c(1, 2, 3,4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

data<-data.frame(id,y,time)

```
        id  y   time    desired lenght
         1  0   1            1
         1  0   2            2
         1  0   3            3
         1  0   4            4
         1  1   5            1
         1  0   6            2
         1  1   7            1
         2  1   1            1
         2  0   2            1
         2  0   3            2
         2  0   4            3
         2  0   5            4
         2  0   6            5
         2  1   7            1
```

Comment: Your two representations of the data do not match. You have different `y` vectors. Also the results don't quite make sense for id=2. You have `y=1` and `time=1` but then at both `time=1`  and `time=2` you have a desired value of "1". Seems at `time=2` the distance should be 2.

Comment: yes im sorry for that. corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bit odd that the length at `y=1` should be 1 rather than 0, but if that's what you want, you can do it with

```
data$desired <- unlist(with(rle(data$y), 
    Map(function(l,v) 
        if(v==1) rep(1, l) else seq.int(l),
    lengths, values))
)
data

#    id y time desired
# 1   1 1    1       1
# 2   1 0    2       1
# 3   1 0    3       2
# 4   1 0    4       3
# 5   1 1    5       1
# 6   1 0    6       1
# 7   1 1    7       1
# 8   2 1    1       1
# 9   2 0    2       1
# 10  2 0    3       2
# 11  2 0    4       3
# 12  2 0    5       4
# 13  2 0    6       5
# 14  2 1    7       1
```

Comment: `rle` - the Swiss Army Knife of `R` tools :-) .